# concatenate null value columns in Tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I use `+` to concatenate several columns's value. But `+` doesnt work if one of that columns has null value. For example

```
Select null+ 'Test'
```

query returns null instead of 'Test'.

What are your advices to solve that problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On versions prior to SQL Server 2012 you should use

```
   Select ISNULL(YourColumn,'') + 'Test' /*Or COALESCE(YourColumn,'')*/
```

to avoid this issue.

There is a connection option [`SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx) but that is deprecated.

SQL Server 2012 introduces the [`CONCAT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) function that treats `NULL` as an empty string when concatenating.

```
SELECT CONCAT(null,'Test')
```

Comment: is there another way to solve it?I am migrating my project from oracle to mssql,i dont wanna add isnull control to every control

Comment: @jhash - The only 3 ways I am aware of are in my answer already. `ISNULL`,`COALESCE`, or `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL`. I'd just add `COALESCE` to all the relevant places as that is standard and will work in both Oracle and SQL Server. Up to you if you want to use deprecated features but they will cease to work in future versions and this connection option is not compatible with some SQL Server functionality. I wouldn't use it myself.

Comment: @jhash - Although actually I am doubting my assertion that it will work on Oracle now. `COALESCE` definitely will but AFAIK Oracle treats the empty string as NULL so I have no idea what the net result will be!

Comment: Not that it probably matters as Oracle doesn't use `+` for string concatenation anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**IsNull**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) :

```
SELECT IsNull(MyColumn, '') + 'Test' ...
```

Comment: is there another way to solve it?I am migrating my project from oracle to mssql,i dont wanna add isnull control to every control

Comment: I think Martin has a solution that would work without changing the query